# SharePoint App cannot see lists

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have an app created on SharePoint 2013. I created 2 lists the same time. But I cannot see the site contents to go to list and manually update items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you do not have a site content or site settings pages you find in a normal page. However, if you know the list internal name, you can build the url from it and go to lit.

```
{App Site URL}/Lists/{List internal name}/AllItems.aspx
```

App Site URL should be like as below example:

https://xyz-4b7e4519af8a29.sharepoint.com/AppInternalName/Lists/ListInternalName/AllItems.aspx

There you will have the normal list view and can do manual CRUD operations.